# convert bit-type days string to string of initial letter of the day in sql

Tags: sql-server, string, date

I have a column Days with a string of 0s and 1s representing days of the week validity, which I need to format or translate for clarity to a string of letters (depending on language) such as 'MTWtFSs' (English) or 'LMmJVSD' (Spanish).

This code works, but seems too long. Any other ideas?

```
DECLARE @i INT = 0
       ,@DaysBits VARCHAR(7) = '110010'
       ,@DaysLetters VARCHAR(7) = ''
       ,@DaysMask VARCHAR(7) = 'MTWtFSs'
WHILE @i < 7 
      BEGIN
            SET @i = @i + 1
            IF ( SUBSTRING(@DaysBits, @i, 1) = 1 ) 
               SET @DaysLetters = @DaysLetters + SUBSTRING(@DaysMask, @i, 1)
            ELSE 
               SET @DaysLetters = @DaysLetters + '_' 
      END
SELECT  @DaysBits AS 'Days Bits'
       ,@DaysLetters AS 'Days Letters'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it with a `case`

```
select case substring(@DaysBits, 1, 1) when 1 then substring(@DaysMask, 1, 1) else '_' end+
       case substring(@DaysBits, 2, 1) when 1 then substring(@DaysMask, 2, 1) else '_' end+
       case substring(@DaysBits, 3, 1) when 1 then substring(@DaysMask, 3, 1) else '_' end+
       case substring(@DaysBits, 4, 1) when 1 then substring(@DaysMask, 4, 1) else '_' end+
       case substring(@DaysBits, 5, 1) when 1 then substring(@DaysMask, 5, 1) else '_' end+
       case substring(@DaysBits, 6, 1) when 1 then substring(@DaysMask, 6, 1) else '_' end+
       case substring(@DaysBits, 7, 1) when 1 then substring(@DaysMask, 7, 1) else '_' end;
```

And if that is a bit to much code for you you could use a numbers table 1-7 and `for xml path` to concatenate the values.

```
select
  (
  select case substring(@DaysBits, N, 1) when 1 then substring(@DaysMask, N, 1) else '_' end
  from (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7)) as T(N)
  order by N
  for xml path('')
  );
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/9526)

Comment: @mikael_eriksson Thanks, although in this case I'm not sure if using less lines of code to achieve the same results is better or not.